# Why do some packets with http protocol have reference to other packets in Wireshark?

Tags: http, tcp, wireshark

I have captured traffic using Wireshark and applied HTTP filter. Some requests have fields [HTTP request 1/(any number)] and [Next request in frame: packet_number].

Why do some packets have [HTTP request 1/2] and [Next request in frame: ###] fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, a browser creates a new TCP session for every HTTP request, but sometimes when two or more resources belong to the same destination the browser will try to `GET` them all in the same TCP session (also referred as the stream in Wireshark). This is when `[HTTP request 1/(any number)]` gets printed out for the first of those requests.

Answer (score 0):

That most likely means the HTTP message span over multiple TCP data packets. A snapshot of what you see would have been helpful.